# Upsell products in drawer cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, up-sells

So, after i add an item to cart it will open a drawer with the information of that product added to cart and below that all his upsell products. In my CartController.php the code is like that:

```
$product = $this->_initProduct();
productId = $this->__(Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getId()));
                    Mage::register('product', Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId));
                    $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_upsell')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml');
                    //set the product
                    $message2 .= $block->toHTml();
```

These upsell products are displayed like card, but i want them to be displayed like a table and i want to display only the image, price, name and i want to add 2 buttons: "Details" that will sent you to product page and "Add to cart" that will add that product also in cart. How can i do this? I tried with $product->getUpSellProductCollection() and foreach but nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody need this, this is the answer:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$upsell = $_product->getUpsellProductCollection();
foreach ($upsell as $product) {
       $productId = $product->getId();
       $model_upsell = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
       $_product_upsell = $model_upsell->load($productId);
       $upsell_name = $_product_upsell->getName();
       $message2.='<img src="'.Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
                   ->getMediaUrl($_product_upsell>getSmallImage()).'"width="200px">' . "<br>";
}
```